# Azure Data Factory Copy activity/Data flow consumes all RUs in CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

We are using `Azure Data Factory` for ETL to push materialized views to our Cosmos DB instance, making sure our production `Azure CosmosDB (SQL API)` is containing all necessary for our users.

The CosmosDB is under constant load as data flows in via speed layer as well. This is expected and currently solved with an autoscaling RU setting.

We have tried these options:

1. An ADF pipeline with `Copy activity` to `upsert` data from `Azure Datalake (Gen2)` (source) to the collection in `Cosmos DB` (sink).
2. An ADF pipeline using DataFlow with a CosmosDB sink and the `Write throughput budget` set to an acceptable level, with `Allow upsert` . Using the same source as previous.

Non the less we see a lot of 429's, our CosmosDB instance overwhelmed and our users experience affected with poor experience, timeouts and slow response times.

Since the copy activity tries to upsert all data as fast and efficient as possible, it consumes all available RUs in a greedy way. Resulting in a lot of 429, our CosmosDB instance overwhelmed, speed layer affected, and our users experience affected with poor experience, timeouts and slow response times.

We hoped the second option with setting the throughput budget would solve the issue, but it has not. Are we doing something wrong?

**Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this? Please advise**

*Edit: Clarifications*

Comment: Are you setting a manual throughput RU value on the sink in the data flow?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Not really. Currently we are running a `Copy activity` with `Write batch size = 5` and `Max concurrent connections = 1`. Also Cosmos DB autoscales to 10000 RU.

Comment: Ok, that's been the only way I could solve this as well. Would be so nice if the copy activity had a "max RU/s usage" setting.