# Azure Data Factory Dataflow CosmosDB Sink "Write throughput budget" doing nothing

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I am seeing pretty much the same behavior as this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61954653/azure-data-factory-copy-activity-data-flow-consumes-all-rus-in-cosmosdb) which I can't comment on as I don't have enough reputation. I have an API that is using cosmos and I have a daily batch job that needs to write into that cosmos instance. When the job kicks off it greatly affects API performance. Scaling up to an insanely high RU solves the issue but it solves it rather or not the "Write throughput budget
" setting is set. So let's assume the API was using 2500 RUS. If I then use Data Flow to scale to 5000 RUs with a 2500 RU threshold it should not affect API performance as there are 2500 RUs still available that data flow is not touching. That is not the case though and we do still a direct performance hit to the API once the data flow job starts copying into CosmosDB. I guess my question is: what exactly is "Write throughput budget" and how do you use it effectively?

Comment: Could you please provide some info like Batch size:, Throughput ( i believe it is 5000)  ,Write throughput budget ,Update method in your cosmosdb sink . Are  u using partition key with high cardinality

Comment: Also is the collection set to Autoscale , if so what is the max RUS

Comment: Batch Size: Default, Throughput: 5000, Write throughput budget: 2500, Update method: Upsert, Partition Key: 10 digit number (high cardinality)

The collection is not set to autoscale. It starts at 2500 manual. The amount of data is about 600K rows from a parquet file. The regular copy activity clocks it around 2GB.

Comment: This is what i would suggest you to do

Change the Throughput  in CosmosDB Sink to 400 , do not specify the Write throughput budget and run a test.  Did you ever  check that the RUS are indeed scaled to 5000 while running the data flow

Comment: Yes, the RUs are indeed scaled to 5000. I will try the test where the throughput is lower than the allocated RUs.

Comment: that would be good

Comment: Ok, so I tested with no write budget and the RUs lower than the allocated amount and the write into cosmos still affected API performance. For the time being, I will just leave the write budget off of the job as it doesn't seem to be doing anything and just crank the RUs up to where the performance hit isn't seen. Seems really wasteful given that the SLA on the batch job is a few hours so doesn't matter long it takes as long as it just doesn't impact performance. I am open to other possibilities. 2nd option is to create a separate read region for the API but that is less than ideal as well.

Comment: @BrandonWatts you could post it and accept(mark) it as the answer.

Comment: @LeonYue I could but it's not really the solution. The question was "What exactly is "Write throughput budget" and how do you use it effectively?" If there is a different forum than StackOverflow to ask that question let me know as I'm still new at this.

Answer (score 0):

The "write throughput budget" refers to the provisioned or allocated capacity for write operations within the database service.

Azure Cosmos DB uses a provisioned throughput model, where you allocate Request Units per Second (RU/s) to handle read and write operations.

Consider using Azure Cosmos DB's auto-scale feature, which dynamically adjusts provisioned throughput based on actual usage patterns. Choose serverless options for scenarios with sporadic or unpredictable write workloads, where resources are allocated on-demand.