# Azure Data Factory data flow - drops null columns

Tags: azure-data-factory

When using a data flow in azure data factory to move data, I've noticed that the data (at the sink) is missing columns that contains NULL values. When using the copy activity to copy the same data, the columns are present in the sink with their NULL values.

Record after a copy activity:
[image: Record after a copy activity]

Record after a data flow:
[image: Record after a data flow]

Source is parquet, sink is azure cosmos db. My goal is to avoid defining any schemas, as I simply want to copy all of the data "as is". I've used the "allow schema drift" option on the source and sink.

I would just use the copy activity, but it doesn't appear to have the ability to define a maximum speed (RU consumption) like the data flow does, so the copy activity ends up consuming all of the cosmos db's RUs very quickly (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61954653/azure-data-factory-copy-activity-data-flow-consumes-all-rus-in-cosmosdb))

---

EDIT:

sink data preview shows all columns
[image: sink data tab]

sink inspect tab shows all columns
[image: sink inspect tab]

Comment: Inside your data flow designer, when you click "data preview" on the sink transformation, do see the columns there that are NULL? Also, check the Inspect tab to make sure those columns are present in the metadata.

Comment: @MarkKromerMSFT - yeah, i see the columns in the data preview as well as the inspect tab for the sink, i'll add a picture to the OP

Comment: Updated my earlier answer with repro findings, see if it helps

Answer (score 2):

Dataflows always skip writing JSON tags with NULLs. There is no workaround currently other than copy activity.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere that I missed?

Comment: I've literally been pulling my hair out for hours now.  Are you kidding me.  You are just going to omit fields w/o any reason or explanation or warning.  Like hey, these null fields are never gonna make it to your output file?

Answer (score 0):

**This is really not a good design or behavior on Microsoft's part**  because you can't Standardize in Cosmos weather to "Keep" or "Remove" null fields in your JSON.
Querying Cosmos
Where field1 = NULL is  completely different than where NOT IS_DEFINED (field1)  and will yield an entirely different result set.

And if your users don't know if the ADF developer used a Dataflow with a Sink vs a Copy Activity in a Pipeline then the may get erroneous results in a query. The only way to ensure you get all the data is to always use:
Where field1 = NULL or where NOT IS_DEFINED (field1)

Users should not have to depend on knowing what kind of ADF functionality was chosen for a specific JSON document in a Cosmos NoSQL collection to do a query.  Plus you can't standardize that you will "Keep" null across all Cosmos documents or you will "Remove" nulls across all Cosmos documents. Unless you force everyone to use Pipelines only or Dataflows only. Depending on the complexity using Pipeline only is not always possible. But using Dataflow only is also not always needed.